# Using Prisma, how can I Insert using $executeRaw function and return the values inserted?

Tags: javascript, sql, node.js, postgresql, prisma

I am trying the following Postgresql query with Prisma's $executeRaw function. But it is not returning the values inserted. Instead only returning the number of records inserted.

```js
await prismaClient.$executeRaw(`
INSERT INTO table1 (name, place, animal, thing)
SELECT * FROM table2
WHERE place = 'California'
RETURNING *;
`);
```

It is returning

```
1
```

While I want the records inserted to be returned. How can that be done?

Comment: https://www.prisma.io/docs/concepts/components/prisma-client/raw-database-access#typing-queryraw-results You can try `queryRaw`.

Comment: Wow! This worked. I thought query is only for querying. Can't use Insert using query. Please add it as answer so I can mark it to be the right answer :)

Answer (score 0):

You are making insert and select from diferent tables. You are inserting in table1 and selecting from table2.
It could be the problem.

Try this.

```
await prismaClient.$executeRaw(`
INSERT INTO table1 (name, place, animal, thing)
SELECT * FROM table1
WHERE place = 'California';
`);
```

Comment: I want to select from table2 and insert into table1. That is not the problem. It is working fine. I tested it. The problem is returning statment. I want the values that are inserted back. I am getting that in SQL editor. But not with Prisma. It is still returning the count of records inserted while I want it to retuirn the record values that are inserted

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to [jian](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15603477/jian) I got the answer

```js
await prismaClient.$queryRaw(`
  INSERT INTO table1 (name, place, animal, thing)
  SELECT * FROM table2
  WHERE place = 'California'
  RETURNING *;
`);
```